# If $\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{y}) = \sin^{-1}(\frac{a}{b})$, does $\frac{x}{y}$ equals $\frac{a}{b}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I was trying to solve the two-sticks-in-the-well problem:

If $\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{y}) = \sin^{-1}(\frac{a}{b})$, does $\frac{x}{y}$ equals $\frac{a}{b}$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts and what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the edit
I think yes cause:
if α = sin-1(x/y) = sin-1(a/b), then sin(α) = (x/y) = (a/b)

But I might going to fast and missing something

Comment: It is true since $\arcsin $ is a one-to-one function. It is false for $\sin$ or $\cos$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The range of the function $y=\arcsin x$ is
$y \in \left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and the domain is
$x \in [-1,1]$. Within these limits, the arcsin function is bijective. That is if $x_1, x_2 \in [-1,1],$ then 
$-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \le \arcsin x_1 = \arcsin x_2 \le \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.